# Insert specific Node in desired Position Linked List on Python

Tags: python

i have sort of problem imagining or solving this, i have this node and list

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, info):
        self.info = info
        self.next = None

class list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__first = None
        self.__last = None
```

and i have to create a function, called indexL(self, info, position), that put the exact node in the desired position, here is what i have for now
(i have created already a method called self.length() to give the size of the list)

```
def indexL(self, info, position):
    longit = self.length()
    n = node(info)
    p = self.__first
    if position == 0:
        self.__first = n
    else:
        if position > 0 and position < longit:
           if position == longit-1:
                self.__last = n
            else:
```

and now i'm stuck there, by the way i can't add any method to the node or use other method of the list, if someone want to help or any recommendation, i would be really grateful

EDIT: in my last comment is more clear if you are confused :P

Comment: it is the entire code of list, sorry i will edit, position = index

Comment: what is `info` and `position` in this case?

Comment: What is the `list` class used for?

Comment: What are you expected to do if `position` > `length`. I'm assuming `position` is an index of some sort.

Comment: the list is to be used as single linked list, if position>length i will put "error, position is outside of the size of the list), what i mean with position, for example, if i want to put 1 node into position 3, i want that, if the size of the list is 4 or more, put that node in that position for example, my list is d-<c-<b-<a, i want to put f in position 1 , i want to f to replace b

Comment: You should traverse the list until the position is reached, as `i = 1 temp = self.__first while(i < positon)  temp = temp.next ##traverse the linked list to find the node before the position`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a `length()` method... all you need to do is iterate over the list until you reach position and update the info:

```
def indexL(self, info, position):
    if not self.__first:
        raise Error("Empty List")

    item = self.__first
    i = 0
    while item:
        if i == position:
            break
        item = item.next
        i += 1
    else:
        raise Error("Position is outside of the size of the list")

    item.info = info        # Replace info
```

Comment: I'd also `info.next = item.next` before the final assignment; without it, you're replacing the tail completely instead of inserting.

Comment: I'm not inserting a node... just replacing the data of the node. So you don't need `item.next`. If you need to delete the node and insert a new node then you need to keep the previous node and handle all sorts of special cases (beginning, end, etc.)

Comment: Yes, it's _replacing_ a node, while the title reads "_Insert_ specific Node in desired Position Linked List on Python".

Comment: Thanks AChampion! it works! replacing, i tried with 9000 for inserting but it doesn't compiles